# Laravel form validation only works when hitting back button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel 4.2. My issue happens after submitting the form with data that will fail during form validation (short pass, invalid email, etc).

My form is at /register. When I submit the form with invalid data, the page goes blank (white) and no data is entered into the database. The validation errors only show up after I hit the back button in the browser.

If I enter valid data, the form submits and adds data to the database correctly, and redirects the user to /account.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like it's something small that I'm overlooking, and it's kicking my ass.

Here's my code...

**User.php**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /** Protect from mass-assignment **/
    protected $fillable = array('username', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation');

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public static $rules = array(
        'username'=>'required|unique:users,username|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password'=>'required|between:8,32|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation'=>'required|between:8,32',
        'email'=>'required|email|unique:users,email'
    );

}
```

**UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends BaseController {

    public function getNew() {
        return View::make('users.new')
            ->with('title', 'Create An Account');
    }   

    public function postCreate() {
        $validation = User::Validate(Input::all());

        if ($validation->passes()) {
            User::create(array(
                'username'=>Input::get('username'),
                'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password')),
                'email'=>Input::get('email')
            ));

            return Redirect::to('account')->with('message', 'Welcome! Your account has been created.');
        } else {
            Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
        }
    }
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('register', array('as'=>'register', 'uses'=>'UsersController@getNew'));

Route::post('register', array('before'=>'csrf', 'uses'=>'UsersController@postCreate'));
```

**new.blade.php**

```
    @if($errors->has())
        <p>The following errors have occured:</p>

        <ul id="form-errors">
            {{ $errors->first('username', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('password', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('password_confirmation', '<li>:message</li>') }}
            {{ $errors->first('email', '<li>:message</li>') }}
        </ul>   
    @endif

    {{ Form::open(array('action'=>'register')) }}

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}<br />
        {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username')) }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address') }}<br />
        {{ Form::text('email', Input::old('email')) }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password') }}<br />
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm Password') }}<br />
        {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
    </p>

    <p>
        {{ Form::submit('Register') }}
    </p>

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

**basemodel.php**

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {

    public static function validate($data) {
        return Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
    }
}
```

Comment: What stack are you running on? There might be a bit more information about the error causing the white screen in the PHP logs.

Comment: You need to return the redirect.

Comment: You're correct. I was able to fix it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `UsersController::postCreate()` function you're not returning the `Redirect::to()` in your `else{}` and so the response isn't being sent back to the user. The controller is just executing without returning anything and so you're left with a blank page.

```
Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
```

needs to become

```
return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
```

Comment: Thank you Wader! I always miss the smallest things.